# Dynamically build eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here's my query that was build so far.

```
$MembersList = User::where('interest', '=', $interest)
                ->where('seeking','=',$seeking)
                ->where('living_addr','LIKE',"%".$address."%")
                ->select('id','firstname','city')
                ->get();
```

Here i want to don't want to search the `$interest` or `$seeking` or `$address` if those are empty.

So, If `$address` is empty then the query should be

```
$MembersList = User::where('interest', '=', $interest)
                ->where('seeking','=',$seeking)
                ->select('id','firstname','city')
                ->get();
```

How can i do this with condition ?

**Update :**

Not only the `$address` field. I should check it for all the fields. If anyone value is empty. It should not consider it in the search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple check the conditions and build the query -

```
$MembersList = User::select('id','firstname','city');
if(!empty($address)) {
    $MembersList->where('living_addr','LIKE',"%".$address."%");
}
if(!empty($interest)) {
    $MembersList->where('interest', '=', $interest);
}
if(!empty($seeking)) {
    $MembersList->where('seeking','=',$seeking);
}
$MembersList = $MembersList->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. let me have  a try with it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to chain it all together.

```
$sql = User::where('interest', '=', $interest);
if (condition) {
    $sql->where('seeking','=',$seeking);
}
$sql->select('id','firstname','city');
$Memberslist = $sql->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To build a dynamic query you will have to use old style if statements:

```
$MembersList = User::where('interest', '=', $interest);
if($address)  $MembersList->where('living_addr','LIKE',"%".$address."%");

$MembersList=$MembersList->where('seeking','=',$seeking)
            ->select('id','firstname','city')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Just replicate the IF structure for all conditions you want to check.